# Fragment switching or Multiple activities?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a two pane master-detail style application with differing views for the tablet and phone version. Is it recommended to have a single activity switching fragments in the phone layout or is it better practice to have two activities, one with each fragment? The android examples have both ways implemented but i am not sure which is the best practice and why?

Comment: Can you link to the example where it only has a single activity (where the aim is dual-pane on devices which can handle it) on phone?

Comment: example of single activity with fragment swapping: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, the example of dual pane showed in the official documentation specifies 2 fragments and 2 activities, but this isn't a choice you have to do. Both are required.

- For phones, activity A shows fragment #1 and activity B shows fragment #2.
- For tablets, activity A shows both fragment #1 and #2, and activity B isn't used.

Comment: +1 this is what I understood from the dual pane example too. But I disagree with "both are required". It's possible to do without Activity B by just swapping out the fragments (or using a FragmentViewPager).

Comment: That's exactly how I've done the recent project. You'll have to put a lot more effort than it seems from the examples, but worth it.

Comment: @DoctororDrive "more effort than it seems" +1 I had to do a lot of back and forth between classes to understand what was going on in small steps when I implemented it

Comment: So which is considered best practice? Having Activity B with its own fragment or just using Activity A and switching two fragments?

Comment: @JohnBaum perhaps you could link the single activity example - I've only seen the dual activity example so far so can't comment on best practices.

Comment: @JohnBaum I used containers and replacing fragments http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html.

Comment: @DoctororDrive The page you linked demonstrates using a single activity, but the method tbruyelle describes includes two activities - which did you use?

Comment: @ataulm I used a single Activity and switched between fragments.

Comment: This is exactly my question.... What are the advantages of one method to the other? The developers page lists both so they dont seem to have a guideline at all for best practice.

Comment: @JohnBaum I prefer using single Activity and Fragments because you will have the same code and the same Activities for both tablet and phone.

Comment: The problem with having a single activity is you have to add code for handling navigation (back and up). Moreover the application will use more memory.

Comment: @tbruyelle why will a single activity and 2 fragments use more memory than 2 activities and 2 fragments?

Comment: @ataulm because memory is released between activity transitions, and not as much between the fragment transitions.

Answer (score 0):

I use fragments for this. On a phone, there's a viewpager which lets the user switch between fragments. On a tablet, fragments are shown at the same time. But of course, it all depends on what your app does.

Depending on your app and on the users, you can have a tab bar that lets users switch the viewpager.

Comment: OP is asking about two solutions to the dual-pane issue, both of which use Fragments. I think your answer could be improved (for clarity) if you used Activities in the explanation of your implementation.